# Find element or attribute value anywhere in XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I am trying to find the value of an element / attribute regardless of where it exists in the XML.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cXML payloadID="12345677-12345567" timestamp="2017-07-26T09:11:05">
  <Header>
    <From>
      <Credential domain="1212">
        <Identity>01235          </Identity>
        <SharedSecret/>
      </Credential>
    </From>
    <To>
      <Credential domain="1212">
        <Identity>01234</Identity>
      </Credential>
    </To>
    <Sender>
      <UserAgent/>
      <Credential domain="8989">
        <Identity>10678</Identity>
        <SharedSecret>Testing123</SharedSecret>
      </Credential>
    </Sender>
  </Header>
  <Request deploymentMode="Prod">
    <ConfirmationRequest>
      <ConfirmationHeader noticeDate="2017-07-26T09:11:05" operation="update" type="detail">
        <Total>
          <Money>0.00</Money>
        </Total>
        <Shipping>
          <Description>Delivery</Description>
        </Shipping>

        <Comments>WO# generated</Comments>
      </ConfirmationHeader>
      <OrderReference orderDate="2017-07-25T15:22:11" orderID="123456780000">
        <DocumentReference payloadID="5678-4567"/>
      </OrderReference>
      <ConfirmationItem quantity="1" lineNumber="1">
        <ConfirmationStatus quantity="1" type="detail">
          <ItemIn quantity="1">
            <ItemID>
              <SupplierPartID>R954-89</SupplierPartID>
            </ItemID>
            <ItemDetail>
              <UnitPrice>
                <Money currency="USD">0.00</Money>
              </UnitPrice>
              <Description>Test Descritpion 1</Description>
              <UnitOfMeasure>QT</UnitOfMeasure>
            </ItemDetail>
          </ItemIn>
        </ConfirmationStatus>
      </ConfirmationItem>
      <ConfirmationItem quantity="1" lineNumber="2">
        <ConfirmationStatus quantity="1" type="detail">
          <ItemIn quantity="1">
            <ItemID>
              <SupplierPartID>Y954-89</SupplierPartID>
            </ItemID>
            <ItemDetail>
              <UnitPrice>
                <Money currency="USD">0.00</Money>
              </UnitPrice>
              <Description>Test Descritpion 2</Description>
              <UnitOfMeasure>QT</UnitOfMeasure>
            </ItemDetail>
          </ItemIn>
        </ConfirmationStatus>
      </ConfirmationItem>

    </ConfirmationRequest>
  </Request>
</cXML>
```

I want to get the value of the `payloadID` on the `DocumentReference` element. This is what I have tried so far:

```
BEGIN
     Declare @Xml xml
     Set @Xml = ('..The XML From Above..' as xml)       
END

--no value comes back
Select c.value('(/*/DocumentReference/@payloadID)[0]','nvarchar(max)') from @Xml.nodes('//cXML') x(c)

--no value comes back
Select c.value('@payloadID','nvarchar(max)') from @Xml.nodes('/cXML/*/DocumentReference') x(c)

--check if element exists and it does
Select @Xml.exist('//DocumentReference');
```

I tried this in an xPath editor: `//DocumentReference/@payloadID`
This does work, but I am not sure what the equivalent syntax is in SQL

Comment: `Select c.value('@payloadID','nvarchar(max)') from @Xml.nodes('//DocumentReference') x(c)`?

Comment: @Siyual, oh man! Similar examples always had a reference to the root element, so I thought I needed it. I never even tried that. If you want to post that as the answer, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.nodes()` (like suggested in comment) is an unecessary overhead...

Better try it like this:

```
SELECT @XML.value('(//DocumentReference/@payloadID)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

And be aware, that `XPath` starts counting at `1`. Your example with `[0]` cannot work...

> ```
> --no value comes back
> Select c.value('(/*/DocumentReference/@payloadID)[0]','nvarchar(max)') from...
> ```